# Tensorflow - Updating weights multiple times using same gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

Training network using gradient descent usually consists of running forward, backward and update passes on a minibatch and then moving to the next one.
I want to run a modified version of this procedure: After running the initial forward and backward passes (getting the loss and the gradients) and making the initial update I want to run forward and update again until a stopping criteria is satisfied.

Normal training algorithm looks like this:

```py
    for mb in get_minibatches():
      loss = forward(mb)
      gradients = backwards()
      weights.update(gradients, step)
```

What I need (note that the gradients are only calculated once):

```py
    for mb in get_minibatches():
      loss = forward(mb)
      gradients = backwards()
      weights.update(gradients, step)

      while (new_loss = forward(mb)) > loss:
        step = step / 2 # actual formula is different
        weights.update(gradients, step)
```

How can I execute my custom sequence of forward+update steps?